# for loop to write multiple files as latex output in python

Tags: python, latex

Hey I'm newbie learning python and LaTeX for an economics course and i have query about how to do a for loop to write LaTex ouput in multiple tex files without repeating codes.

```
result= ['res','res1','res2','res3']
for r in result:
   f = open(r +'.tex', 'w')
   latex= r.summary().as_latex()
   f.write(latex)
   f.close()'
```

The above code gives an *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'summary'*.

The results list contains summary of a regressions that I had run. So each res is a summary of an OLS regression. I want to convert the summary as LATeX code through a for loop instead of writing it like

```
f = open('res.tex', 'w')
f.write(results.summary().as_latex())
f.close()
f = open('res1.tex', 'w')
f.write(res2.summary().as_latex())
f.close()
```

and so on...
Is there any way to do it through a for loop?

Comment: In your example, each `r` is a string instance. This will never have a `summary` method. Is the summary always a string?

Comment: No. The summary is not a string. The type for the variables (res, res1)  showed was _statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper_ .

Comment: Then the MWE is wrong, as there they are definitely strings.

Comment: Sorry as a newbie i'm not sure what you mean by MWE. I changed the  result according to the answer below as 'result= [res,res1,res2,res3]' so its not taken as a string.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "The results list contains summary of a regressions that I had run" however your code

```
result= ['res','res1','res2','res3']
```

clearly has `result` as a list of strings.
This gives your error : *" AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'summary'."*

If you have four variables, then

```
result = [res, res1, res2, res3]
```

would give you a list perhaps of your regressions.

---

It appears you want to walk over a list of results, and a list of filenames.

Something like

```
result = [res, res1, res2, res3]
filename = ['res', 'res1', 'res2', 'res3']
```

which you can do like this

```
for (res, name) in zip(result, filename):
   f = open(name +'.tex', 'w')
   latex= res.summary().as_latex()
   f.write(latex)
   f.close()
```

or even better

```
for (res, name) in zip(result, filename):
   with f = open(name +'.tex', 'w')
       latex = res.summary().as_latex()
       f.write(latex)
```

Comment: I did the change as you suggested, but then instead got another error _TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegressionResultsWrapper' and 'str'_ .

Comment: That's probabily a new question - be specific about which line gives this error

Comment: The line is ' f = open(r +'.tex', 'w')' and the error is as before
_TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegressionResultsWrapper' and 'str'_ .

Comment: `open` takes a filename, and `r` is a `RegressionResultsWrapper` - choose a filename instead, since it's saying it can't add a`RegressionResultsWrapper` and  astring

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong but doesn't that mean for loop will not work in this case, since i have to give file names to each res individually.

Comment: You want to loop over two things; results and strings, so I've added an edit showing how to do this